# Touch on video using swipe js not working with iphone

Tags: javascript, swipe

i using swipe for slider on my website.
when there is a item is video tag or object youtube in slider, can't touch on this item with iphone.
how to fix it?
Sorry for my english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try set z-index for video element